# Why is my DateTime now giving me the month and the date of the month?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I’m doing the code below in my view but I just get the month and number of the month in regards to 12 months of the year like this:

May 5 instead of May 14.

Here’s the code I have in my view:

```
  @{
 DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
 String date = now.ToString("MMM");
}
```

What I want is the month and the date of the month.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
@{
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    int month = now.Month;
    string monthName=now.ToString("m").Split(' ')[1];
    int day=now.Day;
}
```